# Is this too complex of a SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry I didn't know how to abbreviate this for the title in order to make it a viable question.

I have two tables, one is linked to the other via a `FOREIGN KEY`, lets call it ID.

First step,

select all entries excluding the ID in hand from table 1:

```
     SELECT * FROM MyTable1 WHERE ID != 1234;
```

Now, I'd like to bring the second table into the mix. This table has ID as the FK and lets say `CompanyName` as the second field.

To finalise my query, I would like a query that could omit all values from table one that share the`CompanyName` that coincides with the ID in table2.

Is this possible with a single query or am I going overboard?

Comment: Question is too confusing. Make the question simpler for readers to understand.

Comment: looks like possible to me, however you should really post your table structure and sample data for confirmation

Comment: This is as simple as it can get, read it again.

Comment: No, it's not. For one, you can start by cutting out cruft you don't need. That would be trivial. "Now, I'd like to bring the second table into the mix," adds nothing; the phrase "To finalise my query, I would like a query that could..." adds nothing. Also, your question is essentially a "write my code for me" question. You provide no evidence of research or what you've found or what you've tried that didn't work. SO is [not a site for you to get all the help you want](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1394393); it's a site for building a knowledge repository.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Thanks for the answer. This is my only question in over a year, I'm hardly using SO as a place to get my code written or as a 'get all the help you want resource'.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply join the tables and specify that the `CompanyName` must not be equal:

```
select MyTable1.* from MyTable1, MyTable2
where MyTable1.ID = MyTable2.ID
and MyTable1.ID <> 1234
and MyTable1.CompanyName <> MyTable2.CompanyName
```

Comment: This would return entries from Table2, I don't want that. Nice try though.

Comment: Change your select to include the fields you want.

Comment: @jspcal, maybe a left join would be better in this case

Comment: @haleemurAli can you post a better answer? I could upvote it

Comment: You could've skirted around by being insightful as opposed to writing the code - I don't support this kind of answer. Not accepted.

Comment: If you mean close your answer yes, SO isn't the place where you fight to see who can write the code first, it's for people to come to as a knowledge resource.

Comment: You're not making any sense. I've voted to close your question.

Comment: I'm calling you out is what I'm doing. Stop ruining SO by littering it with your rage and unhelpful comments. Do you even see my question ask for code? You lost this argument long ago.

Comment: SO is a place to help the questioner arrive at the answer that's opposite from what you did.

Comment: Not a rant. I'm waiting for an actual answer to my question whilst trying to deter ones like yours. Also having to 'educate' a veteran user btw.

Comment: Priceless. This is the funniest thing I've seen on SO.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT MyTable1.* FROM MyTable1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.ID = 1234 
WHERE MyTable1.ID != 1234 AND MyTable1.CompanyName != table2.CompanyName;
```

I picked up on the tips and reached the answer myself.

Comment: Outer joining a table from which you select no columns makes no sense.